# Why is TS not generating a pure javascript code but it generates a node.js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module

I'm currently learning javascript development - typescript, node.js and express. There is something that I don't understand:

Typescript is a javascript superset and it should generate a classic javascript code from the typescript syntax, right? There is this code for importing modules in my node.js project in `app.ts` file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

which generates an `app.js` file with this code:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// Include dependencies
var express = require("express");
```

AFAIK the `require()` function is not a 'classic' javascript function, but it is a Node.js function for importing modules. This is what I dont understand:

**Why is TS not generating a pure javascript code but it generates a node.js function?**

What If I will be using typescript for a non-node.js project? Will the typescript generate a `require()` function that does not exists? What am I missing?

Comment: How is `require` impure JavaScript?

Comment: Somewhere I read that `require()` is only supported by the newest versions of ECMAscript that is not yet widely supported by the currently used devices and browsers.

Comment: That's not really true. `require` is part of CommonJS, and NodeJS implements CommonJS. You told TypeScript to compile into CommonJS, so it will give you CommonJS code.

Comment: Oh, OK. But what do you specifically mean by "not true"? `require()` is not/will be not a native function of newest JS versions?

Comment: What I meant is that `require` isn't part of ECMAScript, and will probably never be supported by any browser.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. It is an `import` and `export` keyword that is used in ES6: http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html. In this case a third party `require()` function should be obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` you have lines like this

```
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

That is why your typescript is generating such a code. If you want to change your target module system, you have to change the config.

Comment: Oh, it is a matter of TS configuration. In my case there is `"target": "es5", "module": "commonjs",`